# Hide Div based on search content and text value in div

Tags: javascript, html, search, text, show-hide

Hi firstly ty for looking at my code ^^

i have made a working example that hides the content based on the input but the problem is it looks letter for letter so lets say i have this text in my div "yes i know" i have yo start typing with the y to find it because if i type lets say "know" it wont find it

here is the example  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kL6dzqtg/)

and here is my code

I would like it to work that it would look for words in stead exact letter it starts

tyvm in advance ^^

```
$('#my-textbox').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp('^' + value, 'i');

    $('.panel-group .panel').each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('.accordion-toggle', this).text());
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
});
```

Comment: Dear aleksandr, why do you post as negative to my quastion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply remove the ^ from the RegExp. this means it has to start with said string

```
var exp = new RegExp(value, 'i');
```

On this link you can find more info about RegExp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp